# Looking for shape files for major museums in the US.

Tags: geospatial, glam

I have found some individual cities' data but not somewhat comprehensive country wide data. It doesn't have to be perfect, but it would be nice to have most major museums.

Comment: Let me check this: you want the actual shapes of individual museums, i.e. the area they occupy?

Comment: @JanDoggen It's weird, but not as weird as it sounds. Albuquerque has shapefiles for every platted property in the city. Google also appears to have some inside maps, but I think they're primarily for malls so far. Wouldn't necessarily be a bad idea for other large buildings.

Comment: Here is an answer from the GIS site https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/302842/112869

Answer (score 1):

There is a [tag museum](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:tourism%3Dmuseum) in open street map, so this would be the first place to look at for the US. However, 1) you would need to extract the polygons yourself ( using [OVERPASS API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) for example) and  2) Open street map is not guarenteeed to be a complete dataset.

Answer (score 1):

## [Museum Universe Data File (MUDF)](https://www.imls.gov/research-evaluation/data-collection/museum-universe-data-file)

The [Museum Universe Data File](https://data.imls.gov/d/ku5e-zr2b?_ga=2.9600181.1819980787.1542742145-949762418.1542742145) is an evolving list of museums and related organizations in the United States.  It includes basic information on aquariums, arboretums, botanical gardens, art museums, children’s museums, general museums, historic houses and sites, history museums, nature centers, natural history and anthropology museums, planetariums, science and technology centers, specialized museums, and zoos.

[Shapefile for 2015 Q3](https://bowdenweb.com/a/data/museum-universe-data-file/museum-universe-data-file-fy-2015-q3-et8i-mnha.shp.7z) converted from [original GeoJSON dataset](https://data.imls.gov/resource/et8i-mnha.geojson).

### References and Resources

[Museum Universe Data File - imls.gov](https://www.imls.gov/research-evaluation/data-collection/museum-universe-data-file)
[Museum Universe Data File FY 2015 Q3 - Most Current as of 2018-11-20](https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.imls.gov/et8i-mnha)
[Canonical Source](https://data.imls.gov/Museum-Universe-Data-File/Museum-Universe-Data-File-FY-2015-Q3/ku5e-zr2b), however there is no option to export via GeoJSON.
[Interactive Dataset](https://data.imls.gov/d/ku5e-zr2b)
[Data Table](https://data.imls.gov/Museum-Universe-Data-File/Museum-Universe-Data-File-FY-2015-Q3/ku5e-zr2b/data)
[Documentation (PDF)](https://www.imls.gov/sites/default/files/mudf_documenation_2015q3.pdf)
[Geojson](https://data.imls.gov/resource/et8i-mnha.geojson)
[CSV Data File (ZIP)](https://www.imls.gov/sites/default/files/mudf15q3pub_csv.zip)
[API](https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.imls.gov/et8i-mnha)
[JSON](https://data.imls.gov/resource/et8i-mnha.json)

### Possible Solutions/More Data

[Search data.gov for Datasets Tagged with "Museum"](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?tags=museum)
[Search data.gov for Datasets Tagged with "Culture"](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?tags=culture)
[Search data.gov for Datasets Tagged with "History"](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?tags=history)
[Search data.gov for Datasets by Organization "neh.gov"](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?organization=neh-gov)
[Search data.gov for Datasets Tagged with "Art"](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?tags=art)
[Search data.gov for Datasets Tagged with "Art", in a Format of "ZIP"](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?tags=art&res_format=ZIP)
[Search ESRI ArcGIS Open Data for "Museums"](http://hub.arcgis.com/search?q=museums)
[Search ESRI ArcGIS Open Data for "Art"](http://hub.arcgis.com/search?q=art)